# Unit test karma inline modal controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, modal-dialog, karma-jasmine

What I want is to test inline controller in uibModal. If I add this controller as separate js file it works but I need to find a way to test function in inline controller.

**Unit test**

```
/* jshint undef:false*/
(function() {
    'use strict';

    describe('ListingController', function() {
        var listingController, rootScope, scope, state, q, $httpBackend, mockAuthenticationService, modal, actualOptions, stateParams;
        var mockCurrentUser = {id: 1, name: "One, Coordinator", roleId: [3, 10], eauthId: "coordinator1"};
        var mockReview = { reviewId: 1, users: [{id: 1, roleId: 3}, {id: 2, roleId: 3}]};
        var mockReviewUserNotFound = { reviewId: 1, users: [{id: 2, roleId: 3}]};

        beforeEach(module('app'));
        beforeEach(module('listing'));
        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $q, _$state_, _$uibModal_, _$stateParams_, _$httpBackend_, _AuthenticationService_) {
            rootScope = $rootScope;
            scope = rootScope.$new();
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            q = $q;
            state = _$state_;
            stateParams = _$stateParams_;
            mockAuthenticationService = _AuthenticationService_;

            function FakeModal(){
                this.resultDeferred = $q.defer();
                this.result = this.resultDeferred.promise;
            }
            FakeModal.prototype.open = function(options){
                actualOptions = options;
                return this;  };
            FakeModal.prototype.close = function (item) {
                this.resultDeferred.resolve(item);
                $rootScope.$apply(); // Propagate promise resolution to 'then' functions using $apply().
            };
            FakeModal.prototype.dismiss = function (item) {
                this.resultDeferred.reject(item);
                $rootScope.$apply(); // Propagate promise resolution to 'then' functions using $apply().
            };
            modal = new FakeModal();

            spyOn(mockAuthenticationService , 'getLoggedUser').and.callFake(function() {
                var deferred = q.defer();
                deferred.resolve(mockCurrentUser);
                return deferred.promise;
            });

            rootScope.$digest();

            listingController = $controller('ListingController', {
                $scope : scope,
                $uibModal : modal
            });
        }));
        describe('checkUserPermission function',function(){
            it("should call checkUserPermission function and open permission modal", function() {
                listingController.loggedUser = { id: 1};
                listingController.checkUserPermission(mockReviewUserNotFound);
            });
        });
    });
})();
```

**Controller functions**

```
function checkUserPermission (data) {
            var userFound = _.find(data.users, function(user) {
                return user.id === listingvm.loggedUser.id && user && (user.roleId === 3 || user.roleId === 2);
            });

            if (userFound) {
                listingvm.goToPlaning(data.reviewId, data.users, true);
            } else {
                openPermissionModal();
            }
        }

        function openPermissionModal() {
            listingvm.cancelConfirmInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: true,
                size: 'lg',
                templateUrl: "src/app/modules/listing/views/modals/permission.modal.view.html",
                backdrop: 'static',
                controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
                    $scope.confirmModal = function() {
                        $uibModalInstance.close();
                    };
                }
            });
        }
```

With not using inline controller I have solution to make new unit test for that controller and do something like:

```
 $uibModalInstance = jasmine.createSpyObj('$uibModalInstance', ['close', `'dismiss']);`
```

and in it function just do something like:

```
 describe('confirmModal function',function(){
      it("should call confirmModal", function() {
        errorModalController.confirmModal();

        expect($uibModalInstance.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    });
```

But is there a way to test this inline function $scope.confirmModal in same it function for checkUserPermission?